# Extending a Hilbert space isometrically

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, linear-algebra

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $X$ be a topological vector space.

- Under what conditions on the topologies of $X$ and $H$ does there exist an injective, continuous linear map $f : H \to X$?

Supposing that such an injective embedding $f : H \to X$ exists, consider the topological closure $F := \overline{fH}$ in $X$.

- When does the closure $F$ admit the structure of a Fréchet space, with $f : H \to F$ an isometric embedding?

Comment: The obvious idea to embed the separable Hilbert space into a sequentially complete locally convex space is to find a sequence $x_n$ which converges fast to $0$ and to define $f:\ell_2 \to X$ by
$f((a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N})= \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n x_n$.
This map will be injective if the sequence is *topologically linearly
m-independent$. This is discussed on page 37 in the book *Barrelled locally convex spaces* of Bonet and Perez-Carreras.

The second question is not clear to me: If there is no norm on the *Frechet* space $F$, what do you mean by isometric? On the other hand, if $F$ is ...

Comment: ...normed and $f$ is an isometry then $f(H)$ is complete and
hence closed in $X$ (if you assume that $X$ is Hausdorff). 

Comment: Since you can always embed $H$ isometrically into $H \times Y$ for any topological vector space $Y$, there would seem to be plenty of scope.

Comment: @Jochen Wengenroth: I specifically made no additional assumptions on the Hilbert space nor the larger topological space $X$, such as separability or local convexity. Your remark on the separable case is interesting, and I thank you for making the point. For the second question, I mean to say, "when does F admit the structure of a Fréchet space?" Certainly, if its topology is completely metrizable, then the metric on $F$ will be an extension of the metric from $H$.

Comment: Are the inclusions of Levi-Sobolev spaces $H^s(T^n)\rightarrow H^t(T^n)$ on products $T^n$ of circles, for $s>t$, the kind of example you want? If so, it illustrates that a Hilbert-space structure can get weaker...

Comment: Aren't Gelfand triples giving examples of what you want http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Gelfand+triple

Comment: @Tom: Even if there is any metric on $F$ inducing the vector space topology such that $f$ is an isometry then $f(H)$ will be already
a completely metrizable topological vector space. This not obvious (since the uniformities may be a priori different) but true because of a theorem of Victor Klee (solving a problem of Banach). Therefore,
$F=f(H)$ still holds.